# Can I create an Apache server and use No-IP (or similar) in Windows to host a site?

Tags: windows, apache, dns, ip

The title says almost everything. I want to use apache under windows and then redirect one or more domains to my computer using a service like No-IP. Is it possible?

Comment: I wonder why they'd care to build web servers for Windows if that wasn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you just need to set port forwarding to your local machine (PORT 80 for HTTP, 443 for SSL, 21 for FTP ( if you want to run a ftp server aswell)) on your router, and set a dynamic dns there that points to NO-IP. Most likely you can add one DynDNS entry.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You don't even need a Dynamic DNS service (like no-ip) if you have a static IP address. In that case, just register a domain name and create two DNS records -

```
NAME                    TYPE   VALUE
example.com.            A      public.ip.address.here
www.example.com.        CNAME  example.com.
```

Most ISPs now assign static IPs (even if they claim otherwise), and if not, you can get one for a small fee ($5/month extra). Or upgrade your account to business class.

This way you don't have to introduce another layer (Dynamic DNS) into your set up.

Then install a WAMP such as - [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) (really popular here) - [UniformServer](http://www.uniformserver.com/) -
[Wamp-Developer Pro](http://www.devside.net/server/webdeveloper) (the one I use) -
[WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) (another good one)

You'll also need to port-forward your router (ports 80 and 443) to the LAN IP, and create two rules in the Windows Firewall to unblock incoming port 80 and 443 requests.

The only thing that can go wrong is if your ISP blocks incoming port 80 (http) and 443 (https) requests. You can call and get them to unblock that, or again, update the account to business class to remove all the headaches.